# CreateIconFromResourceEx on canvas.mozFetchAsStream, how to feed the stream?

Tags: winapi, canvas, firefox-addon, icons, jsctypes

My goal is to make a `.ico` or a `HICON` out of canvas drawing. Below is a snippet for windows. What it does is lets you file pick. You pick an image and then it adds canvas to the document in current tab (at way bottom) and then draws the 32px logo on cavas and then on that it overlays the browsed image. Now im trying to us jsctypes of winapi `CreateIconFromResourceEx` with `canvas.mozFetchAsStream` but I can't figure it out.

I'm stuck on this line: `alert(streamData)`.

Also for `PBYTE` in my `CreateIconFromResourceEx` is it correct to set it to `ctypes.unsigned_char.ptr`? (Because byte I know is just `ctypes.unsigned_char` right?)

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm');

var user32 = ctypes.open('user32.dll');


/* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
* HICON WINAPI CreateIconFromResourceEx(
* __in_  PBYTE pbIconBits,
* __in_  DWORD cbIconBits,
* __in_  BOOL fIcon,
* __in_  DWORD dwVersion,
* __in_  int cxDesired,
* __in_  int cyDesired,
* __in_  UINT uFlags
* );
*/
var CreateIconFromResourceEx = user32.declare('CreateIconFromResourceEx', ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.voidptr_t,
    ctypes.unsigned_char.ptr, /* PBYTE pbIconBits */
    ctypes.unsigned_long, /* DWORD cbIconBits */
    ctypes.bool, /* BOOL fIcon */
    ctypes.unsigned_long, /* DWORD dwVersion */
    ctypes.int, /* int cxDesired */
    ctypes.int, /* int cyDesired */
    ctypes.unsigned_int /* UINT uFlags */
);

/////////////// running stuff below. above was just defining stuff
var me = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null);

var canvas = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
gBrowser.contentDocument.documentElement.appendChild(canvas);

var fp = Cc['@mozilla.org/filepicker;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIFilePicker);
fp.init(window, 'Select Badge Image', Ci.nsIFilePicker.modeOpen);
fp.appendFilters(Ci.nsIFilePicker.filterAll | Ci.nsIFilePicker.filterText);

var rv = fp.show();
if (rv == Ci.nsIFilePicker.returnOK || rv == Ci.nsIFilePicker.returnReplace) {
  var file = fp.file;
  // Get the path as string. Note that you usually won't 
  // need to work with the string paths.
  var path = fp.file.path;


    var oImage = new Image();
    oImage.src = 'chrome://branding/content/icon32.png'; //Services.io.newFileURI(file).spec;
    oImage.onload = function() {
        alert('loaded')
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

        var oImage = new Image();
        oImage.src = Services.io.newFileURI(file).spec;
        oImage.onload = function() {
            alert('loaded')
            ctx.drawImage(this, canvas.width-this.width, canvas.height-this.width);
            //mozFetchAsStream stuff: https://github.com/mozilla/build-partner-repacks/blob/885947b726c5d6e131af4e4aae621d51109bded4/partners/yandex-drp/distribution/extensions/vb%40yandex.ru/cbapp/parts/screenshotsGrabber.js#L295
            var asyncStreamCallback = {
                    onInputStreamReady: function (streamData) {
                        alert(streamData)
                    },
                    QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([
                        Ci.nsISupports,
                        Ci.nsIInputStreamCallback
                    ])
                };
            canvas.mozFetchAsStream(asyncStreamCallback, 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon')
            //now do canvas.mozGetAFile(blob) then reconstruct icon
        }
    }
}

////////////////

user32.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with your code. But since your objective is to turn the canvas contents to an ICO, here is another way (somewaht more straightfoward I dare to say).

```js
// assuming ctx holds your drawings
let imgdata = ctx.getImageData(0,0,32,32); // this is a 32x32 icon, right?
let icoencoder = Cc["@mozilla.org/image/encoder;2?type=image/vnd.microsoft.icon"].createInstance(Ci.imgIEncoder);
icoencoder.initFromData(imgdata.data, imgdata.data.length, 32, 32, 32*4, Ci.imgIEncoder.INPUT_FORMAT_RGBA, "");
icoencoder.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInputStream);

var icofile = new FileUtils.File("/path/to/canvas.ico");
var output = FileUtils.openSafeFileOutputStream(icofile);
NetUtil.asyncCopy(icoencoder, output, youroptionalcallback);
```

The result is a proper `canvas.ico` file which you can pass to the windows api functions.

Comment: If anyone else knows whats going on with my code above I would still apprecaite an answer to that for learning purposes, I'm going with paa's altenrtative method because its so sweet.

Comment: Dang man it's not working :( The ico file is made but its not proper or something, maybe xp uses differnt type? Same situation, if I use a hardcodeded path a an ico i downloaded it works.

Comment: Well, I creted an ICO file and it is ok. In what way it doesn't work for you?

Comment: On WinXP in the file exploerer, typically .ico show the image as its own icon, in the case of your method and my original `mozFetchAsStream` method the icon is an "unknown" image. And the winapi method does not apply the icon to the windows. Both ways, it works in Win7 though, which is so weird.

Comment: Ok, it seems that Windows XP does not support ICO with PNG format. If you change the last argument of `initFromData` to "format=bmp" the situation improves, marginally :-(

Comment: Thanks man! I'll test that out and let you know! Seriously thanks for your help :) I was hoping to still learn about using for fun `CreateIconFromResourceEx` do you know anything about that? :)

Comment: Also is there anyway to do this `format=bmp` thing from `mozFetchAsStream`? Because `mozFetchAsStream` is async and i think this method is not.

Comment: Hey man I tried using the `format=bmp` thing and it didnt work :( its just now a dark gray or a light gray :(

Comment: I found something interesting: https://github.com/centurn/Griffontune/blob/de5a0ea53bcda239bdacae027561281f1761ad86/modules/WebappsInstaller.jsm#L442